# Unable to resolve dependency tree @angularx-social-login

Tags: angular, angular-social-login

I'm using angular 12 and I need to implement a social login using @abacritt/angularx-social-login. When I use npm i --save @abacritt/angularx-social-login, I get the error

> Unable to resolve dependency tree
> While resolving: app-name
> Found: @angular/common@12.2.16
> @angular/common@~12.2.0 from the root project
>
> Could not resolve dependency:
> peer @angular/common@"^13.0.0 || ^14.0.0" from @abacritt/angularx-social-login@1.2.1
> @abacritt/angularx-social-login@"*" from the root project
> Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

I can't upgrade the angular version, and when I tried to use npm i --save angularx-social-login, some parts are deprecated and don't work anymore.

How can I install a @abacritt/angularx-social-login compatible with angular 12?

Comment: try running the npm install with the --force option

Comment: @edjm I managed to install but when I try to use I get the error "cannot find module 'angularx-social-login' or its corresponding type declarations

Comment: Using force is bad advice it quite clearly says in that error message that the version you're installing requires Angular 13+ and you're using Angular 12.  On that NPM page it tells you the Angular compatability versions (it looks like they moved the package after the version that supports Angular 12) https://www.npmjs.com/package/@abacritt/angularx-social-login. Just use `angularx-social-login:4` to install the older version that supports Angular 12. What parts of that are not working?

Comment: @Alex do I need to use npm install angularx-social-login:4 to install or just angularx-social-login is fine? The part where I use this.authService.signIn(GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID) was returning "cannot read properties of undefined (reading signIn), and I saw some people saying that it might happen because it's the older version of angularx-social-login

Comment: From their docs it looks like `angularx-social-login`. It also seems like they address the issue with the signIn service in their new documentation as a limitation imposed by Google. https://github.com/abacritt/angularx-social-login#sign-in-with-google

Comment: @Alex I subscribed to the authentication state, now I'm in doubt about where do I have to add the GoogleSigninButtonDirective to use the sign in with Google button

Answer (score 1):

In angular 12 use just npm i --save angularx-social-login:4
@abacritt/angularx-social-login is for Angular 13 and 14. Check github repo https://github.com/abacritt/angularx-social-login#subscribe-to-the-authentication-state

Answer (score 0):

angularx-social-login:4 @abacritt/angularx-social-login will be deprecated.

For Angular 12, there has been an updated @abacritt/angularx-social-login version `1.2.4-ngx12.0` which you can [read docs from npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@abacritt/angularx-social-login/v/1.2.4-ngx12.0).

You can install by

```
npm i @abacritt/angularx-social-login@1.2.4-ngx12.0
```

Since Docs is not updated yet, you should follow as bleow when you import:

```
import { SocialLoginModule, SocialAuthServiceConfig } from '@abacritt/angularx-social-login';
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to remove this line from package.json and package-lock.json:

```
"angularx-social-login": "^4.1.0",
```

make sure you are using the new version on angular social login:

```
npm i @abacritt/angularx-social-login

import { SocialLoginModule, SocialAuthServiceConfig } from '@abacritt/angularx-social-login';
```